# Provide extendable Typescript interface in library

Tags: node.js, typescript, inheritance, interface

I'm building a library with Typescript that should support third-party plugins. The constructor function of the library should accept the options for the core library and for all plugins, since the module will load them in the constructor.

Is it possible to provide a base `Options` interface that each plugin can extend to add their own properties and types, so that throughout the top-level application (which uses the library and plugins), the `Options` interface reflects both the core options and those of the plugins?

So with a dependency structure like this:

```
- user-app
|- my-library
|- my-library-plugin-a
|- my-library-plugin-b
```

Where `my-library` defines the following:

```
export interface Options {
  coreOption : string;
}
```

And `my-library-plugin-a` extends it as follows:

```
export interface PluginAOptions extends Options {
  pluginA : boolean;
}
```

And `my-library-plugin-b` extends it as follows:

```
export interface PluginBOptions extends Options {
  pluginB : Record<string, string>;
}
```

To the developer of `user-app`, which has all three modules in its dependencies, the Options interface as exported from `my-library` should look like this:

```
interface Options {
  coreOption : string;
  pluginA : boolean;
  pluginB : Record<string, string>;
}
```

So that's what their autocomplete should show, and what the Typescript compiler should check for.

Is something like this at all possible with Typescript?

Comment: @Li357 The key word in my question is 'third-party'. In other words, I can't extract the types into a shared module, since I'm not the only one who will have types. Other devs should be able to make plugins and publish them to npm as they like.

Comment: Okay, then just export your types from your library so that one can import and extend them.

Comment: My point is that plugin A and plugin B should both extend the type from the core library, and a user of all three modules should see the unified type containing the core and everything plugins A and B added. Just extending the types in the plugins is of course easy to do. But I'm looking for a way to let these extensions 'bubble up' to the top program.

Comment: I've updated my original question in an attempt to make my question clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot expect to get the whole extended options from the `my-library`.

This is not about TypeScript, but about how dependency works.
`my-library` knows nothing about the plugins and it supposed to.
If it somehow can export options added by the plugins, it will be depends on those plugins, making the plugin architecture pointless.

In the `user-app`, you should simply use the options from `plugin-a` and `plugin-b` and combines them.

```
const theOption: PluginAOptions & PluginBOptions = { ... }
```

`user-app` is the one who knows and decided to use `plugin-a` and `plugin-b`.
That's why it should and can use the types from those plugins.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I figured it wouldn't be possible, but I thought I'd ask just in case there was a way to achieve this after all.

Comment: Please note: this answer is outdated, see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77011839/2732818).

Answer (score 0):

This is possible using typescript's [declaration merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html) feature:

`my-library`:

```
export interface Options {
  coreOption : string;
}
```

`my-library-plugin-a`:

```
import {Options} from 'my-library';

export module 'my-library' {
    export interface Options {
      pluginA: boolean;
    }
}
```

`my-library-plugin-b`:

```
import {Options} from 'my-library';

export module 'my-library' {
    export interface Options {
      pluginB: Record<string, string>;
    }
}
```